# Printing part of a dictionary entry?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I've been trying to find a way to print out a certain part of a dictionary's value, but haven't found what I'm looking for. Does anyone know if there is a way to print out one value? Similar to this:

```
rows["id"] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
print(rows["id"(5)])
```

The second line doesn't work.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what basically row is: it's a dictionary with 'id' as a key and then the list as the value of the key

```
rows = {"id":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}
rows['id'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>>rows['id'][5]
6
>>> rows['id'][:5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

hope it helps you to understand

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
print(rows["id"][5])
```

First you select the value which corresponds to the `'id'` key (a list in this case). Then you select the value from the list using the index `[5]`.